# How to play a Lottie animation only once in LottieView?

Tags: react-native, lottie, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have developed a bottom tab navigator and used Lottie animations as icons. I want them to autoplay and get played only once when it's in focus (like the Binance app). I have tried with `loop={false}` but that stops it from animating altogether. The code is as follow:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

import Home from './Home';
import Create from './Create';
import Messages from './Messages';
import Forum from './Forum';
import Profile from './Profile';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let filePath;

          switch (route.name) {
            case 'Home':
              filePath = require('../tabanimations/hometab.json');
              break;
            case 'Messages':
              filePath = require('../tabanimations/messagestab.json');
              break;
            case 'Create':
              filePath = require('../tabanimations/hometab.json');
              break;
            case 'Forum':
              filePath = require('../tabanimations/forumtab.json');
            case 'Profile':
              filePath = require('../tabanimations/profiletab.json');

              break;
          }

          return <LottieView source={filePath} autoPlay={focused} />;
        },
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Create" component={Create} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Forum" component={Forum} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

How to play the animation only once on focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `loop={false}` and `autoPlay={false}` then use `play()` to run on focus
your code may be lookalike this

```js
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
    return <CustomTab focused={focused} color={color} size={size} route={route}/>
}


const CustomTab = ({ focused, color, size, route}) => {

    const ref = React.useRef();
    let filePath;

    //on focus change the anim will play
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(focused && ref.current){
            ref.current?.play();
        }
    }, [focused, ref.current]);

    switch (route.name) {
        case 'Home':
            filePath = require('../tabanimations/hometab.json');
            break;
        case 'Messages':
            filePath = require('../tabanimations/messagestab.json');
            break;
        case 'Create':
            filePath = require('../tabanimations/hometab.json');
            break;
        case 'Forum':
            filePath = require('../tabanimations/forumtab.json');
        case 'Profile':
            filePath = require('../tabanimations/profiletab.json');

            break;
    }

    return (
        <LottieView 
            ref={ref}
            loop={false}
            source={filePath} 
            autoPlay={false} />
    );
};
```

you can also use play like this `ref.current?.play(0, 1)` to ensure it always start from 0
you can see `LottieView` Methods [here](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods-imperative-api)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Set `loop={false}` for playing the animation only once.

```
export default function App = () => {

    const ref = React.useRef();

    const playAnim = () => {
       ref.current?.play();
    }

    const pauseAnim = () => {
       ref.current?.pause();
    }

    return (
        <LottieView 
            ref={ref}
            loop={false}
            source={filePath} 
            autoPlay={false} />
    );
};
```